# SecItem methods fail with -34018

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I use code below to safely store strings on iOS.  Sometimes `SecItemCopyMatching()` and then also `SecItemAdd()` fail and return error code `-34018`.  I've not been able to find this code; what does it mean?

```
NSMutableDictionary* query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[query setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[query setObject:account forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[query setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];

OSStatus error = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);
if (error == errSecSuccess)
{
    // Do update.
    NSDictionary* attributesToUpdate;
    attributesToUpdate = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                     forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    error = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributesToUpdate);
    if (error != errSecSuccess)
    {
        NBLog(@"SecItemUpdate failed: %d", (int)error);
        result = NO;
    }
}
else if (error == errSecItemNotFound)
{
    // Do add.
    [query setObject:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    error = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);
    if (error != errSecSuccess)
    {
        NBLog(@"SecItemAdd failed: %d", (int)error);
        result = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing failures on a device or in the Simulator?

Comment: @zaph On a device. Any idea what this particular (probably Apple internal) error code means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-34018` is `errSecMissingEntitlement` according to [osstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=34018)

`Internal error when a required entitlement isn't present.`

For iOS 10+ you need a `.entitlements` file to access the keychain. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.keystore.access-keychain-keys</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.keystore.device</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```